# Is it possible to count how many value enter in the most recent input for a column in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a way to count how many data is enter into a column for the most recent input? If use find max, it will only find the latest and ignoring the one that is seconds or minute earlier that are enter at the same time frame.

[image]

Comment: how are you defining most recent?

Answer (score 0):

```
=count(A:A)

'or if they are not all numbers count the number of non blank cells

=counta(A:A)
```

Not sure if this meets your criteria of most recent entries.

Comment: I have change the question to more precise@Forward Ed

Comment: still not precise enough.  Are you looking for all entries that occur before a certain time indicated in the third column?  ie are you entering a date and time in another cell, and you want to know how many entries occurred before that time? Is still hard to determine how you are defining "recent entries".

Comment: I manage to find the latest entry with the helper cell. But tried another method but it always return 0. '=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$20<>"")*(AND($C$2:$C$20>($E$2-($F$2/86400)),$C$2:$C$20<($F$2/86400+$E$2))))'

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting in A1 and the column on the right(the dates) is in column c then...

=index(A1:C100,arrayformula(large(if(C1:C100=large(C1:C100,1),row(C1:C100)),row(1:1))),1)